# Cual seria la forma optima de hacer esto?

Tags: reactjs

```js
onInputChange (e) {
  this.setState({ username: e.target.value });
}
onInputChange2 (e) {
  this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
}

onInputChange3 (e) {
  this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
}
```

Inputs

```js
<input type="text" required className="form-control" placeholder="Username" onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)} />
  <input type="email" required className="form-control" placeholder="Email" onChange={this.onInputChange2.bind(this)} />
  <input type="password" required className="form-control" placeholder="Password" onChange={this.onInputChange3.bind(this)} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asocia un solo listener para todos los inputs controlados y por medio de `bind` pasas el nombre de la propiedad a la que corresponde en el estado:

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this, 'username')}/>
<input type="text" onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this, 'email')}/>
<input type="text" onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this, 'password')}/>
```

Ya que has usado `bind` para pasar argumentos, sigues manteniendo el parámetro `event`:

```
onInputChange (property, e) {
    this.setState({
      [property]: e.target.value
    });
}
```

Comment: Y despues en el onsubmit que uso para hacer el fetch que tendria que cambiar? onSubmit (e) {
  fetch (`http://localhost:3000/api/users/create/${this.state.username}/${this.state.email}/${this.state.password}`, {
    method: 'POST'
  })
}

Comment: ¿Envias los datos por parámetros, es decir `http://.../param1/param2/param3`, o por medio del cuerpo de la petición?

Comment: Los envio por parametros

Comment: Yo veo tu fetch bien, claro, le falta el then para obtener la respuesta. ¿Te falla al hacer la petición?

Comment: El problema de esta forma es que me esta creando con valores undefined al hacer la peticion :p

Comment: Ésto no tiene relevancia con el fetch. De hecho, si puedes escribir en los inputs significa que están guardando correctamente los valores en e estado. Una pregunta, ¿Guardas tus los valores `username`, `email` y `password` en el estado, o dentro de un objeto que está dentro del estado?

Comment: No sabria responder esa pregunta jaja aun no aprendo muy bien el tema de objetos en js

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51799/discussion-between-guzgarcia-and-santiago-dantuoni).